# How to use f string in a path location

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I simply want to use `filename` variable in my f sting.
What am I missing here?

```
# generating file name
filename = 'AG' + datetime.date.today().strftime("%m%d%Y")

# saving file
df.to_csv(f'C:\Users\username\Documents\folder1\folder2\{filename}.csv', index=False, sep=',')
```

**Error:**

```
    df.to_csv(f'C:\Users\username\Documents\folder1\folder2\{filename}.csv', index=False, sep=',')
              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: try replacing all "\" with "\\"

Comment: Alternatively, leave the `"\"` in place but use `fr` in front of the string to combine raw string and formatted string.

Comment: This is why we have [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)  

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As tiega mentioned, the issue you are having is with the `\` in constructing the f string.

As a more solid approach, you may consider using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to manipulate paths.

Examples:

```
import datetime 
from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath

filename = 'AG' + datetime.date.today().strftime("%m%d%Y")
fp=Path(r'C:/Users/username/Documents/folder1/folder2', filename+'.csv')
# you could actually use this unmodified to open the file on Windows...

print(PureWindowsPath(fp))
# show the Windows presentation of that path
# C:Users\username\Documents\folder1\folder2\AG05072020.csv
```

Comment: One thing, what if I need to generate path with this slashes "/" ?

Comment: The `/` character is [prohibited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) file name character on Windows.

Comment: The question is asking about f-string in Pathlib, not raw-string.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with backslashes in the string, not with fstring formatting. You need to escape the back slashes in your Windows style path by using `\\`, because a single backslash indicates an escape character, for example `\n` for a newline character and `\t` for a tab.

As @dawg mentioned, you can also combine `f` with the `r` [raw-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#raw-f-strings) so python doesn't escape any characters.

Comment: You may wish to mention that there is a [raw version](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#raw-f-strings) of f strings that avoids this issue...